# Obtain value from JSON variable inside javascript

Tags: javascript

How to obtain value from JSON element being created dynamically. Example below. I was wondering if there is way to get the value from previous element 'top' using some javascript. (Please update the title if its incorrect or misleading)

[Following this example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ULNrC/)

```
var info = [
{
  src: "http://dummyimage.com/55x80/0d0.png/fff",
  pos: {
    top: 93,
    left: 70
  },
  rotate: -10,
  zIndex: 3
},
{
  src: "http://dummyimage.com/55x80/d00.png/fff",
  pos: {
    top: previousElement(top) + some dynamic value added at run time,
    left: 70
  },
  rotate: 0,
 zIndex: 2
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do this, you can calculate it as you go based on the index.

But... if you insist:

Assuming your array is a JS literal (and not JSON, which is different) you can use a simple counter.

Using the fact assignment returns the assigned value (this is kind of ugly though):

```
var top = 93;
var info = [
{
  src: "http://dummyimage.com/55x80/0d0.png/fff",
  pos: {
    top: top,
    left: 70
  },
  rotate: -10,
  zIndex: 3
},
{
  src: "http://dummyimage.com/55x80/d00.png/fff",
  pos: {
    top: top = top + (some dynamic value added at run time),
    left: 70
  },
  rotate: 0,
 zIndex: 2
}          //... keep doing top = top + sometDynamicValue on all elements
]
```

A more isolated example might be:

```
var c = 0,    
    arr = [
       {a:c = c + 5},
       {a:c = c + 5},
       {a:c = c + 5},
       {a:c = c + 5},
       {a:c = c + 5},
    ]
```

Which creates an array of objects with an increasing by 5 `a` property.

Comment: Do you have a good javascript book to suggest based on the question I have asked?

Comment: @java_dude if you know another programming language already then "The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford is solid, otherwise John Resig (of jQuery fame) has a nice series of lectures at Khan Academy you can start with :)

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is way to get the value from previous element 'top' using some javascript

`info` is an array so all you need to do is index into it then access the `prop` object i.e.

```
var prevTop = info[someIndex].pos.top;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple syntax to get the value from the previous element in an array literal in Javascript. You have to reference it by index, like this:

```
pos: {
  top: info[0].pos.top + value
  left: 70
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function DoOffset(data, offset)
{
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        data[i].pos.top = data[i - 1].pos.top + offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the info array to change the value:

```
for(var i = 1, len = info.length; i < len; i++) {
  info[i].pos.top = info[i - 1].pos.top + newValue;
}
```